# Getting the number of satellites in android

Tags: android

Below is some code to get the number of satellites.

The problem is it is always returning result zero. I mean `satI.hanNext() returns 'false'` always. Latitude and Longitude return expected results. Can someone help me?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status);
    manager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    GpsStatus.Listener GPSListner = new GpsStatus.Listener() {
        public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            GpsStatus status = manager.getGpsStatus(null);

            Iterable sats = status.getSatellites();
            Iterator satI = sats.iterator();
            count = 0;

            while(satI.hasNext()){
                GpsSatellite gpssatellite = (GpsSatellite) satI.next();
                if (gpssatellite.usedInFix()){
                    count++;
                }
            }

        }
    };

}
```

Comment: You might not yet have connected to any satellites.... You can check the `int event` against the constants mentioned in the docs to see which one will tell you when a satellite is fixed. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html

Comment: Are you running this in the simulator/genymotion or on a physical device?

Comment: - I'm using mobile device (LG-Gflex) 'Chris'
- I can see my location exactly with longitude and latitude. I think it means that mobile phone has connected already.  'cricket_007'
Thank you!  : )